# Reset a event on click with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm using the [jQuery FeatureList plugin](http://www.jscodes.com/codes/code08/) with 2 `<ul>` lists that I show/hide using previous/next buttons.

I did the following:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.featureList( //List 1
            $("#tabs li a"),
            $("#output li"), {
                start_item : 0
            }
        );
        
        $.featureList( //List 2
            $("#tabs2 li a"),
            $("#output2 li"), {
                start_item : 0
            }
        );
        
        $('.ftprev').click(function() { //Prev button
        $(this).fadeOut();
        $('#tabs').fadeIn();
        $('#tabs2').fadeOut();
        $('#output').fadeIn();
        $('#output2').fadeOut();
        $('.ftnext').fadeIn();
        }); 
        
        $('.ftnext').click(function() { //next button
        $(this).fadeOut();
        $('#tabs').fadeOut();
        $('#tabs2').fadeIn();
        $('#output').fadeOut();
        $('#output2').fadeIn();
        $('.ftprev').fadeIn();
        }); 
        
    });
```

It works, but I'd like to make the 1st item of the list 'current' when when a click on a prev/next button. Otherwise, my lists aren't synchronized, which is pretty ugly...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark (without being able to see the actual HTML code), but I'd say you need to add:

```
$('#tabs').find('li').removeClass(); // removes 'current' class from any li that already has it
$('#tabs').find('li').filter(':first').addClass('current');
```

to the 'prev' button click function, and:

```
$('#tabs2').find('li').removeClass(); // removes 'current' class from any li that already has it
$('#tabs2').find('li').filter(':first').addClass('current');
```

to the 'next' button.

If this doen't work, post a jsfiddle of the code and I'll investigate further.